# Rails Public Key Encryption - Decryption to happen offline

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to  protect some highly confidential information at the highest level. I planning to go with public key encryption to secure this information.

Plan:
The encryption key will be on the server and will be used to encrypt the information. The decryption key will be kept offline and will be used to decrypt the information whenever required.

I tried to go with https://github.com/spikex/strongbox but how do I make the decryption offline?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'offline'? Do you mean an offline browser or in an application? If you encrypt on the server side then you should be fine just downloading it and using software like pgp to decrypt it. And all of this security is on top of SSL right?

Comment: offline browser?Could you please throw some light on PGP?I have very less idea in terms of security?